# unexpected token "indent" in jade file

Tags: node.js, pug

I got `node.js express` app using `jade`. And I use `jade mixins`. I edited jade file, after that got error on `44 line`:

```
unexpected token "indent"
42| -i++
43|
> 44| include select
45|
46| mixin mainInputs()
```

`select` is `jade` file in the same directory with target `mixin`.

On picture you can see that there is no extra spacing (dot signs in sublime) on `line 44`

[image: peace of code where I got error unexpected token "indent"]

I already run command `Indentation: Convert to Spaces` in `sublime text 3` but got the same error.

I tried to rename file `select.jade` to `selectFile.jade` to exclude confusion with `select` html tag, but still got the same error.

**Update:**

I tested `select.jade` independently:

```
select.jade:3
    1| include labelFor
    2| mixin select(id, text, placeholder)            
  > 3|     mixin labelFor(id, text)
    4|     select(id="#{id}", name="#{text}", data-placeholder="#{placeholder}")
    5|         option
    6| 

unexpected token "indent"
```

Then I tested `labelFor.jade`:

```
mixin labelFor(id, text)
    div
        div.label
            label(for="#{id}")= text
        br
```

`labelFor.jade` executed without errors.

I searched tabs `\t` in file `select.jade`. But it contains only spaces, no tabs.

Comment: I believe you need an space after the hyphen `/^-/` on line 42: `- i++`

Comment: Have you tried rendering `select.jade` directly? The issue might be in it and the error is just being thrown at `include select`.

Comment: Jade hates the mixtures of spaces and tabs. Make sure that you actually use spaces or tabs right there.

Comment: @Nico space after the hyphen on line 42 did not help

Comment: How about doing that + adding four spaces before the `-`? Indent that

Comment: @Nico the same error.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski direct rendering gives me new data, but still no solution.

Comment: @tymeJV `select.jade` has no tabs (`\t`), only spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in extra spaces after line

```
mixin select(id, text, placeholder)
```

in file `select.jade`.
It was:

```
'include labelFor\nmixin select(id, text, placeholder)            \n    mixin labelFor(id, text)\n    select(id="#{id}", name="#{text}", data-placeholder="#{placeholder}")\n        option\n\n'
```

After I change it to ...

```
'include labelFor\nmixin select(id, text, placeholder)\n    mixin labelFor(id, text)\n    select(id="#{id}", name="#{text}", data-placeholder="#{placeholder}")\n        option\n\n'
```

... error fly away.